# Android: Shrink animation using animator

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I am animating in the following way,

There are 2 layouts (both are relative layouts), layout1, which will be hidden initially, layout2 will be shown to the user initially.

once the animation starts layout1, will be made visible and layout2 will be scaled using the animator as follows,

```
Animator scalexAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout2, "scaleX", 1f, 0f);
Animator scaleyAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout2, "scaleY", 1f, 0f);
Animator pivotxAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout2, "pivotX", <maxWidth>);
Animator pivotyAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout2, "pivotY", <maxheight/2>);

AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playTogether(pivotxAnimator, pivotyAnimator, scalexAnimator, scaleyAnimator);

animatorSet.start();
```

This starts the animation and the layout2 gets shrinked,but the aspect ratio is never maintained, what I mean to say is the animation follows these steps,

1. Firstly the height reduces.
2. Next the width gets reduced.
3. Height reduces again.
4. Width again.

this goes on and it will stop once the final given ratio(0.5) is achieved.

This does not give shrinking effect, I tried with animation class as follows,

```
Animation shrinkAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1,0.5f,1,05f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

layout2.startAnimation(shrinkAnimation);
```

this will work perfectly and I will get a exact shrinking effect, aspect ratio is maintained, but the problem I face in the above implementation is the position of the layout2 is changed, but the button retain their position (layout2 has 4 buttons and button click works on the old button positions, even though the user can't see any buttons there, I read in some posts that this is expected), so I had to disable the buttons manually, this is a overhead so I wanted to avoid using Animation class, and went for ObjectAnimator.

So is there a way in ObjectAnimator to get the same shrinking effect?